# DNS server knows authority but does not provide answer

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to connect to an address that is accessible via a VPN. My ISP's DNS server seems to know where the authorities for the domain are, but can't return the answer/IP address. When using the authority directly I can get the IP though.

```
selene:app-resource-hub work$ dig jenkins.tescloud.com +all @2001:8b0:856:1::1

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> jenkins.tescloud.com +all @2001:8b0:856:1::1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32447
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jenkins.tescloud.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jenkins.tescloud.com.   47  IN  CNAME   jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tescloud.com.       161304  IN  NS  ns-1057.awsdns-04.org.
tescloud.com.       161304  IN  NS  ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
tescloud.com.       161304  IN  NS  ns-399.awsdns-49.com.
tescloud.com.       161304  IN  NS  ns-831.awsdns-39.net.

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:8b0:856:1::1#53(2001:8b0:856:1::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 16 12:56:15 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 212


selene:app-resource-hub work$ dig jenkins.tescloud.com +all @ns-1057.awsdns-04.org.

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> jenkins.tescloud.com +all @ns-1057.awsdns-04.org.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 628
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jenkins.tescloud.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jenkins.tescloud.com.   60  IN  CNAME   jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com.
jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com. 60 IN A    10.17.12.222

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tescloud.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1057.awsdns-04.org.
tescloud.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
tescloud.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-399.awsdns-49.com.
tescloud.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-831.awsdns-39.net.

;; Query time: 278 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.196.33#53(205.251.196.33)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 16 12:56:26 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 228




selene:service-site-assets work$ dig jenkins-
az1.management.tescloud.com. +all @2001:8b0:856:1::1

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com. +all @2001:8b0:856:1::1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47843
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com. IN    A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tescloud.com.       158420  IN  NS  ns-1057.awsdns-04.org.
tescloud.com.       158420  IN  NS  ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
tescloud.com.       158420  IN  NS  ns-399.awsdns-49.com.
tescloud.com.       158420  IN  NS  ns-831.awsdns-39.net.

;; Query time: 103 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:8b0:856:1::1#53(2001:8b0:856:1::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 16 13:44:19 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 190
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an answer. It's the CNAME record in the first example. The remote server isn't actually required to do the secondary lookup from the CNAME to the final result for you, although nearly everyone always does. So your result isn't wrong, it's just odd. If you want to continue investing, the next thing to look at would be if the server you sent the first question to can resolve `jenkins-az1.management.tescloud.com.` as it should.

Comment: I've added the log of that request to the bottom - it doesn't seem to be able to find that either.

Comment: You'll probably have to log in to that machine and see what happens when you try to do the lookup from there. A DNS response packet does not have enough information in it to tell what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

The third query that you performed is the pertinent one. You are seeing a non-authoritative reply with zero answers and a code of `NOERROR`. This means "there are no records with that name and type, but there are other records with that name and a different type". It's similar to `NXDOMAIN`, but is stating that other records with that name *do* exist. In other words, the information wasn't there when your ISP asked for it and it has remembered this.

As for why your ISP hasn't forgotten this...look at your SOA record:

```
tescloud.com.           900     IN      SOA     ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

The last digit in that SOA record is known as the `NCACHE` value, or negative caching value. This is your instruction to nameservers on the internet on how long they should remember the absence of a record. (i.e. how long to remember a "negative" response)

You are currently instructing DNS servers on the internet to remember a negative response for 86400 seconds, which is 24 hours. Many nameservers will enforce a maximum negative caching period that is less than this, but some won't, and odds are high that when you were performing these tests the ISP's nameservers still had the absence of that record negative cached.

This problem will probably sort itself out sometime within the next 24 hours, but in the meantime you should probably lower your `NCACHE` value to something more reasonable. (an hour at most)